# How do I go to the next conflict in the Xcode merge tool?

Tags: xcode, git, merge, keyboard-shortcuts

When I choose to merge a git branch into another via Xcode 5, I get an interface that shows me all the files that are going to be changed including those with conflicts. Before I go ahead with the merge, I am supposed to click on each file with a red C and fix the conflicts.

Imagine one of the files has 100 changes and only 3 of them are in conflict. How can I easily jump to the next conflict in the file? (Besides either manually scrolling and looking for something red, or by tapping the next arrow button 100 times.)

**Update**: This is specifically referring to the **merge window** you access by invoking the Source Control > (working copy) > **Merge to/from branch** command which displays a window such as:

[image]
([image source](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7))

Answer (score 20):

You can do it by pressing

- cmd + D for next conflict
- cmd + shift + D for previous conflict

Comment: This is the best way to do this, someone give this guy a green check! :)

Comment: this are the short cut for file merge. we are talking here about the xcode built in merge tool. and not File merge.

Answer (score 14):

Arrow keys!

Down arrow to go to the next issue, left and right keys to chose the code. You may need to click on the frame between your two sources to enter this mode.

Comment: Using the down array will navigate to the next change, but what Senseful was looking for (and me too) is to jump to the next red/conflicted change. In a file with dozens of changes, it's tedious to press down, down, down until a conflicted change is found.

Comment: Same here as for Marimba.  What I am looking for is the next Red Flagged conflict, not next change.

Comment: I deleted the answer that you attempted to add a "does not work!" comment to @AlexZavatone -- I recommend filing an enhancement request with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com and ask them to enable "jump to next issue" & "jump to previous issue" properly for the merge window.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I'm happy you deleted it.  It's pretty dangerous.  It actually cancels the merge when you try it.  Cost me about 1/2 an hour when I tried it when I was in the middle of one.